# Fantasy (American) Football 2013 - Who's in?

Tags: discussion

**UPDATE:** I have created the league. Ten teams. First come, first serve.

League: [Sports SE Fantasy Football](http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/tools/join?leagueId=516096)

Password: Sports53

I scheduled the draft for Sunday, 18 August 2013 at 8:30pm EDT, but that is up for negotiation.

**FILLED!**

---

As a means of community interaction, Sports SE would like to introduce an SE fantasy (American) football league for the upcoming 2013 football season that include members of the community.

Anybody interested? Newcomers and experienced fantasy football players welcome! Commit by August 8th to reserve your spot in the league.

State your intentions to reserve your spot below with the fantasy platform† you would like to use (I use ESPN...but NFL.com and Yahoo! are other popular options).

†<sub>By default, [ESPN](http://games.espn.go.com/frontpage/football) will be our fantasy platform unless we request and agree to a different platform.</sub>

Comment: imho yahoo as the best phone app out there.

Comment: @chrisjlee We have four teams unclaimed if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

I look forward to dominating the regular season and losing in the first round of the playoffs.

Comment: Always happens to me...best regular season record, out first round of playoffs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in and do not care where we host it.

Answer (score 1):

I am taking on commissioner duties in another league I play in (a Yahoo league) but I would be fine participating in this one also - just don't ask me to be commish ;)

Comment: I shall commish (if no objections)

Answer (score 1):

Damn, for a second I thought the question is about *football* ;)

I am certainly interested in participating fantasy sports, but I do not follow american football beyond a couple of games during the regular season and a couple of games during the playoffs. So I feel I must pass...

(I might check if there's interest for a Fantasy Premier League Season)

Comment: Had to specify :) It may be something that gets you more interested in American football because you want to follow your players to see if they did well. Hope to get you sometime! (Go for it!)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not in. It clearly divides Sports SE. This could've been rallied in the chat as well.

Comment: Would like education on "clearly divides Sports SE." I understand not everyone is into American-football, but to quench such an effort to encourage [interdisciplinary] community interaction is asinine. Anybody can feel free to encourage community interaction, including possible creation of chatrooms (eg, the user-created "Cricket Fans Club") and [blogs](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/372/527). Also, considering the number of users that *regularly* use the chatroom vs. the total number of *regular* users on Sports SE, our reach and visibility is greater this way. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Really? I'm actually much closer friends with the guys I play fantasy football with than almost any other circle of people I know.

Comment: @edmastermind29 On the divide part: that's just the way I feel about that. 
On the chat part: I could've left that part.